# GIT: last branch state to a new branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches:
 - development;
 - new-feature (from *development*);
and 40 commits in branch *new-feature*.
I need just to set **all changes** (last *new-feature* state) to a new branch *new-feature-single*.
I can't make rebase, because *development* branch now is too new and it is too hard to make rebase throw all 40 commits.

Comment: How will `new-feature-single` be different from `new-feature` when you're done? Will it be identical (until you start committing to both branches), or somehow different?

Comment: `new-feature-single` just needs to have changes like `new-feature`, but just have to be with one commit that would have all changes in one

Comment: OK, so you want to squash all those commits into a single commit - should it have the same ancestor as `new-feature`?

Comment: I doesn't matter, just new branch with one commit that will have all changes

Comment: Is it acceptable to you to just rebase your feature branch and squash all of  your commits, so that you only have one commit on your feature branch?  You can do this with an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what I *think* you asked for, although I'm not totally clear on what you hope to achieve:

```
$ git checkout -b new-feature-single development
  # make a new branch, starting from development/HEAD, with no new commits
$ git merge --squash new-feature
  # apply all the changes from new-feature
$ git commit
  # create a single commit with all those changes
```

Note that merging this with `new-feature` later won't behave well, because git sees you making the changes twice *independently*, and can't tell they're related.

Comment: Yes, thats it! I suspected it is --squash command, but I could not understand how to use it... In my case belonging to `new-feature` branch is not nessassary. I just needed to have my changes (`independent` changes is even better), as was described in question. So your answer is absolutely right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, find the common ancestor for your "development" and "new-feature" branches. From your description, it may very well be the commit "development" currently points to, but there's a handy command to find out for certain called [merge-base](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base):

`git merge-base new-feature development`

Let's assume for discussion that the above command spits out "abc123".
Next create a new branch named "new-feature-single" based on commit "abc123":

`git checkout -b new-feature-single abc123`

You should now have "new-feature-single" checked out, and this new branch points to the same parent as where your "new-feature" branch started from.

Finally, merge into "new-feature-single" the commits from "new-feature", and squash them all down to a single commit:

`git merge --squash new-feature`

The "new-feature-single" branch now has all of the changes from "new-feature" combined into a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another branch new-feature-single.
2. Add a remote upstream in new-feature-single to new-feature: git remote add new-feature .
3. Checkout to new-feature-single branch.
4. Pull changes from new-feature to new-feature-single: git pull new-feature

Tip: List all origin and other remote url's connected to branch: git remote -v

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
git checkout -b new-feature-single new-feature
```

That creates a new branch `new-feature-single` that points at the same commit that `new-feature` currently does. That seems to be what you are wanting to do, but if it isn't, perhaps some additional clarification is needed...

One of your comments seems to indicate that, after this, you want to convert `new-feature-single` to a single-commit accomplishing the same changes as the sequence of commits in `new-feature`. After the above step, you could accomplish that by running `git rebase -i development..HEAD`, and changing all actions except the first line to "squash" (or simply "s"). If you have done the above step, then this will not touch your `new-feature` branch, but will leave `new-feature-single` with a single commit on it, branched from the same original point, and containing the cumulative changes of the `new-feature` commit sequence.

Comment: It creates a new branch like old one with same 40 commits. I need to have  new branch with one commit that will have all changes